# Vue 3 + Module Federation

Tags: vue.js, webpack, webpack-module-federation

I am trying to build a simple micro-frontend example using Vue3 and Module Federation but I have a collision problem.

I have the code here:
https://github.com/ghalex/mf-example

There are only two mf:

- container (Vue3)
- auth (Vue3)

The problem I have is that when I import the App.vue component:

```js
// index.js - in container
import App from './components/App.vue'
```

```js
// indexAuth.js - in auth
import App from './components/App.vue'
```

in the **auth** module and load the module in container the App.vue component is overwritten.

Is there any webpack settings am I missing to make sure each component is loaded separately ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem, it is a `webpack-dev-server` v4 [bug](https://github.com/webpack/webpack-dev-server/issues/2692). I downgraded to v3 and everything works fine.